# Query return more than one row?

Tags: mysql

I am creating pagination for alphabet A-Z using php with mysql. I am having single record in my tables for alphabet A. When I querying the record, it will return more than one row instead of single row. Also linked tables contains only single row of record for A's movie id. There is no one to many relationship in any tables. Kindly correct by below query if I did any mistakes in that. Thanks in Advance.

```
select 
    M.name, 
    M.id, (select year(M.released_date))as year, 
    MS.storyrating,
    S.screenplayrating,   
    MS.dialoguerating, 
    MS.directionrating,
    MS.musicrating, 
    MS.bgmrating, 
    MS.cinematographyrating, 
    MS.characterizationrating, 
    MS.shotlocationrating, 
    MS.editingrating, 
    MS.productionrating,
    MI.director,
    MI.musicdirector 
from tttbl_movie M, tttbl_movie_info MI, tttbl_movie_score MS 
where M.id=MI.movie_id 
    and M.id=MS.movie_id 
    AND M.name 'A%' OR M.name 'a%' 
ORDER BY M.name ASC LIMIT 0,2;
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your ORDER BY like

```
ORDER BY M.name ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Also you are missing the `like` in your `OR` clause which I assume is a typo since you say that you are getting 2 records.

Comment: oops. I did mistakes when pasting query in stack overflow Actually my query having like key word.  Suppose if I have more than one record in alphabet A means, how it will return all the record starting with alphabet A, if i set limit to 1?

Comment: @Janaki:- If you want to get all the records which are starting with `A` then you simply need to remove the `LIMIT 1;` part

Comment: @Janaki:- On a side note try to avoid comma seperated JOINS. They are not recommended anymore. Instead try to use explicit JOINS.

Answer (score 0):

You have not like clause in your code

```
select 
 M.name, 
 M.id, 
 year(M.released_date  as year, 
 MS.storyrating,
 S.screenplayrating,   
 MS.dialoguerating, 
 MS.directionrating,
 MS.musicrating,
 MS.bgmrating, 
 MS.cinematographyrating, 
 MS.characterizationrating, 
 MS.shotlocationrating, 
 MS.editingrating, 
 MS.productionrating,
 MI.director,
 MI.musicdirector 
 from tttbl_movie M, tttbl_movie_info MI, tttbl_movie_score MS 
  where M.id=MI.movie_id 
 and M.id=MS.movie_id 
 AND M.name  like 'A%' OR M.name like 'a%' ORDER BY M.name ASC LIMIT 0,2;
```

and if you need it eventually limit 1

```
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need include the `LIKE` keyword and also I think you should put parenthesis for the `OR` part

```
where M.id=MI.movie_id 
  and M.id=MS.movie_id 
  and (M.name LIKE 'A%' OR M.name LIKE 'a%')
ORDER BY M.name ASC;
```